# How can I pass an error on a multiple promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

So basically I am trying to create an Error handler by passing an error value which in my case is a number for a status code like 400, 500, etc.
Now the problem is when the `catch` catches the error, which contains a value of the status code returned from the previous promise. When I log the value it logs the value correctly, but when I reject it and pass the value so it will be caught on the next promise's `catch`, it says that the value is undefined.

Here's the error code:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError
>   [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: undefined

JS:

```
const findFromModel = async (model, query) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        model = model instanceof Object ? model : {};
        if (model) {
            model.findOne(query, (err, obj) => {
                if (obj) {
                    resolve(obj);
                } else {
                    reject(400);
                }
            });
        } else {
            reject(400);
        }
    });
}

const makeOrder = async (title, body, userQuery) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        title = (typeof title === 'string' && title.length > 0) ? title : '';
        body = (typeof body === 'string' && body.length > 0) ? body : '';
        if (title && body) {
            findFromModel(userModel, userQuery)
                .then(user => resolve(user))
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err); // logs 400
                    reject(err); // Undefined
                });
         } else {
             reject(400);
         }
    });
}
```

Execute the promise:

```
makeOrder('test', 'this is body', {id: 'test'})
    .then(obj => res.send(obj))
    .catch(err => res.sendStatus(err.message));
```

I just move from es5 to es6, so if you got any better ideas to improve my code, that will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: You never define the property `message`. Do you mean `err` instead of `err.message`?

Comment: It is actually because in my project when the promise is resolved, I might run a few more functions that might throw a new Error object. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use `async` function, you can reduce your code more.

`Promise` error would becomes exceptions so use `try...catch` to deal with it.

Return from `async` function is effectively `resolve` the promise, throw an error is effectively `reject` it. (just like they're in `Promise`)

```
const makeOrder = async (title, body, userQuery) => {
  title = (typeof title === 'string' && title.length > 0) ? title : '';
  body = (typeof body === 'string' && body.length > 0) ? body : '';
  if (title && body) {
    try{
      let user = await findFromModel(userModel, userQuery)
      return user
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err); // logs 400
      throw err;
    }
    throw 400;
  }
}
```

---

even if you want to use the old ways, it's commonly done with

```
return findFromModel(userModel, userQuery)
   .catch(err => {console.log(err); throw err;});
```